# Why the plugin gluonfx-maven-plugin generates a link error

Tags: android, maven, hyperlink

When I launch the following command
mvn -e -Pandroid gluonfx:link

it generates this error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:link (default-cli) on project gluon-singleviewproject2: **Linking failed** -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
olivier@rog:/media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2$ cat /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/log/process-link-1661334011027.log

This is the logs
Command Line

/home/olivier/.gluon/substrate/Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/dummy.o /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/launcher.o /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/javafx_adapter.o /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/touch_events.o /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/glibc_shim.o /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/attach_adapter.o /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/logger.o /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/tmp/SVM-1661333829754/com.gluonapplication.gluonapplication.o -ljava -lnio -lzip -lnet -lprefs -ljvm -lfdlibm -lz -ldl -lj2pkcs11 -ljaas -lextnet -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fPIC -Wl,--rosegment,--gc-sections,-z,noexecstack -shared -landroid -llog -lffi -llibchelper -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--whole-archive -lprism_es2_monocle -lglass_monocle -ljavafx_font_freetype -ljavafx_iio -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lGLESv2 -lEGL -lfreetype -o /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/libGluon-SingleViewProject2.so -L/home/olivier/.gluon/substrate/javafxStaticSdk/19-ea+8/android-aarch64/sdk/lib -L/opt/graalvm/ce-java17-22.1.0.1/lib/svm/clibraries/27/android-aarch64 -L/home/olivier/.gluon/substrate/javaStaticSdk/18-ea+prep18-8/android-aarch64/staticjdk/lib/static -L/media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/lib -Wl,--whole-archive /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/lib/libdisplay.a /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/lib/liblifecycle.a /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/lib/libstatusbar.a /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/lib/libstorage.a /media/DATA/dev/IdeaProjects/Gluon-SingleViewProject2/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/lib/libutil.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
Output

/home/olivier/.gluon/substrate/Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--rosegment'
/home/olivier/.gluon/substrate/Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**my configuration is** :
ubuntu 22.04
Java 17
graalvm ce-java17-22.1.0.1

I use the sample gluon project

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
<javafx.version>18.0.2</javafx.version>
<attach.version>4.0.15</attach.version>
<gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.15</gluonfx.plugin.version>
<javafx.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.plugin.version>
com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Update both properties as shown below to these versions and above.

```
<properties>
        <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
        <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.16</gluonfx.plugin.version>
</properties>
```